# how to use Zend_Registry::getInstance

Tags: php

```
    <?php

        require_once('Zend/Registry.php'); 
        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance(); 
        $registry['name'] = 'Quentin Zervaas'; 
        echo sprintf('My name is %s', $registry['name']);

    ?>
```

Question:
what does this line mean? `$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();`And how to use this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Registry functions as application level storage where you can store variables, objects or anything else which you need during the execution of the application.

The below statement returns the object of Zend_Registry class using the singleton pattern.

```
Zend_Registry::getInstance();
```

To add the value to registry.

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('variableName', 'value');
or
Zend_Registry::set('variableName', $value);
```

And this is how you get the value

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->get('variableName');
or
Zend_Registry::get('variableName');
```

Answer (score 0):

The getInstance() method returns the singleton registry object. This registry object is iterable, making all values stored in the registry easily accessible. For example.

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();

foreach ($registry as $index => $value) {
    echo "Registry index $index contains:\n";
    var_dump($value);
}
```